# Core-data with SenTestCase class : unexpected error

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, sentestingkit

I am working on an application which stores and retrieves data from sqlite db, using core data. For this I have created a separate class which acts like a data link layer - LocalDBController

Below is the implementation of one of its methods- selectAddressWithAddressId:

```
- (NSDictionary *)selectAddressWithAddressId:(NSString *)addressId
{
    NSDictionary *dictToReturn = nil;

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"address_id == %@",addressId];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Address" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc]; // returning nil when invoked from test case class
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *err = nil;
    NSArray *array = [self.moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];

    // some more code...

    return dictToReturn;
}
```

Now I am trying to implement a test case class for it (SenTestCase class).

I have written below init method in LocalDBController class, so that it uses the default persistent store if value of environment variable is 'Run' and uses in-memory persistent store if value of environment variable is 'Test':

```
- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // initializing moc based on if run setting is used or test is used
        if ([[[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment] objectForKey:@"TARGET"] isEqualToString:@"TEST"]) {

            NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
            NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
            [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:NULL];
            self.moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
            self.moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;
        }
        else
        {
            self.moc = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
        }

    }

    return self;
}
```

In my test class I am trying to invoke below method:

```
STAssertNotNil([self.localDBController selectAddressWithAddressId:@"123"], @"No data found");
```

Problem is-

> In this case, value of **entityDescription** obtained in **selectAddressWithAddressId:** method is nil, though the value of self.moc is not nil. So it
>   is throwing this exception msg in console: **raised
>   executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity..**

If I execute the above method from the class which is not included in my test case bundle, say appDelegate, it works fine.

Can anyone suggest me if I am doing anything wrong in it?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this?

Comment: no answer till now :-(